# Preparation of chess openings and all about chess?

Tags: beginner

I am an enthusiastic player of chess...and a full time working professional...

I have following questions regarding chess to develop my game:

1. How to prepare fundamental opening lines to play as white or black...which openings to start with?
2. How to master the well established book openings for various games along with their approaches/ideologies/commentaries...
3. Please tell me which best books to refer or which chess software to be purchased...for doing so? I won't mind purchasing the same or getting premium memberships, if any??
4. I am good at playing middle games with tactics and exploiting opportunities...but always lose time in opening phase and generally lost the game due to time overruns...i tried playing 10 min live games on chess.com
5. What is all about chess engines...repertoires...pgn etc.
6. How to play further on an independent computer and to record my moves for further analysis after having played with book openings..?
7. Please tell me about ratings??? how a player becomes IM, GM so on so forth...

Is there anybody who can truly help to get answers to these questions or suggest me some readings or website references to get solved the same...thanks in advance to all of you who can please help me out...

Comment: I think you should ask each question separately. There are too many things to answer here.

Comment: Also, browse this site and you may find a few of these answers already.

Comment: I agree that it should be multiple questions, and that many have answers already. The underlying question is what I should do to improve with the limited time I have. The easiest answer is to go over each of your games right after you play them and think about how you could have improved

Answer (score 3):

> I am an enthusiastic player of chess...and a full time working professional...

This makes your job more difficult. There are lots of material out there, but you will need to manage your time to coordinate your work and chess studying.

> How to prepare fundamental opening lines to play as white or black...which openings to start with?

It depends on your preferences, but no matter which opening you choose, you can get a good insight of it from *Starting Out* series.

If you wish to play King's gambit just find *Starting Out King's Gambit* book and so on.

These books describe general moves, tell you if certain line requires **thorough study** or if you can just get by with general opening principles. They also mention typical endings and middlegame structures characteristic for the opening.

All in all I find them to be a great starting reference for a beginner.

> How to master the well established book openings for various games along with their approaches/ideologies/commentaries...

Once you learn the basics, you will need stronger opening books and you will need middlegame/endgame books.

For this you will need to ask a separate question here and people will be able to recommend you something. At this moment it is too broad and opening-dependable.

> Please tell me which best books to refer or which chess software to be purchased...for doing so? I won't mind purchasing the same or
>   getting premium memberships, if any??

For learning software, you could use *ChessBase*. They also offer **videos that explain openings/endgames/middlegames...**

*Fritz*, *Houdini*, *Rybka* are some of the strong chess engines. You could also get *Stockfish* as **it is free** and is strong as well.

> I am good at playing middle games with tactics and exploiting
>   opportunities...but always lose time in opening phase and generally
>   lost the game due to time overruns...i tried playing 10 min live games
>   on chess.com

Knowing your openings will solve this problem.

> What is all about chess engines...repertoires...pgn etc.

I do not understand this one.

> How to play further on an independent computer and to record my moves for further analysis after having played with book openings..?

Any engine does this automatically as far as I know. The game only needs to be saved and you can replay it. I think that it is auto-saved by default.

You also have an option for engine to analyze your game which is good to see where did you go wrong.

During play there is an option to "turn on the Coach" where engine can warn you if you made a bad move or can suggest a move if you are in doubt.

Still, it is best to pick an engine and ask this as a separate question.

> Please tell me about ratings??? how a player becomes IM, GM so on so forth...

As far as I know, you need 2400 rating and to fulfill IM norm. For GM you need rating greater than 2500 and also 3 title norms. More about this can be found in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_titles).

> Is there anybody who can truly help to get answers to these questions
>   or suggest me some readings or website references to get solved the
>   same...thanks in advance to all of you who can please help me out...

I think I just did :)

Welcome to Chess SE, I hope this answer helped you a little.

In the future try to ask questions that can have short answers so you can avoid negative points. You can start by reading through the help section in your upper right corner. I would start with [the tour](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tour).

Best regards and good luck in your study!